# Order Line quantity sum total SQL calculation

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I have Order:

[image: Order table]

I have OrderLine:

[image: OrderLine table]

I want to show which product has been sold the most.

I want to sum every quantity in orderline where it belongs to an order which has status 'completed'

Looking at the data, we see only `orderID = 3` has `orderstatus = Completed`, therefore we only want `OrderLine` for `OrderID = 3` - which is `OrderLineID = 6` and `OrderLineID = 7`.

So our expected result would be `ProductID 1` with `Quantity 11` as follows:

> ProductID|OrderLineQuantity
>
> -------1-----|----------11-----------

My code so far produces an error:

> Column 'OrderLine.ProductID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

My code:

```
SELECT OrderLine.ProductID, SUM(OrderLineQuantity)FROM OrderLine Inner Join [Order] ON OrderLine.OrderID = [Order].OrderID  WHERE OrderStatus = 'Completed'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `GROUP BY` to fix the syntax problem, and then something else to get the top product:

```
SELECT TOP (1) ol.ProductID, SUM(ol.OrderLineQuantity)
FROM OrderLine ol Inner Join
     [Order] o
      ON ol.OrderID = o.OrderID
WHERE o.OrderStatus = 'Completed'
GROUP BY ol.ProductID
ORDER BY SUM(ol.OrderLineQuantity) DESC;
```

Comment: This works, however what what does TOP (1) mean? and DESC at the end? i would like to see, say - the top 10 most popular products

Comment: The code from **Gordon Linoff** is perfect. You can add: `SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT * FROM Table;` To view top records. The DESC means **Descending** The way he orders the table.

Comment: yes, i agree, perfect, i changed it to TOP (10) for top 10 products :)

Comment: @BingoDingo . . . Of course you can return as many rows as you want.  I chose "1" because the question says:  "I want to show which product has been sold the most.".